# how to insert specific data on specific id in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

i have 2 query first one is

```
SELECT stdntCode 
FROM dbo.CourseStudent 
WHERE(Status = 'Active') AND (CrsID = 1) AND (GrpID = 8)
```

second one is insert

```
INSERT INTO StudentExam (ExamID, CrsID, stdntCode, [Degree], StudGrpID, IsAttend, Notes, dateexam, [date])
VALUES(4, 3, stdntCode, 8.0, 1, 1, N'', '2023-01-17', '2023-02-01');
```

i want to insert this data to my first query i want replace stdntCode in my insert query with stdntCode list from my first query
thank you

i try that query

```
insert into StudentExam (stdntCode ,ExamID, CrsID, [Degree], StudGrpID, IsAttend, Notes, dateexam, [date])
select (SELECT stdntCode
FROM dbo.CourseStudent
WHERE(Status = 'Active') AND (CrsID = 1) AND (GrpID = 8)) as IDClient, 
  (4, 3,0, 1, 1, N'', '2023-01-17', '2023-02-01');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide the column values as part of a single *select* statement, like the following:

```
insert into StudentExam (stdntCode ,ExamID, CrsID, [Degree], StudGrpID, IsAttend, Notes, dateexam, [date])
select stdntCode, 4, 3, 0, 1, 1, N'', '2023-01-17', '2023-02-01'
from dbo.CourseStudent
where Status = 'Active' and CrsID = 1 and GrpID = 8;
```